# Simple python reading thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I want to ask a simple question am using threads in python but only in sending using TCP
so my code

```
class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__ (self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        
    def run(self):
        #time.sleep(30)
        print "File will be sent now"
            from ftplib import FTP
            ftp = FTP('192.168.1.3')
            ftp.login('user', 'user')
            file = open('Number', 'rb')
            ftp.storbinary('STOR newNumber.txt', file)
```

I can't understand how to make simple reading thread while true thread.read()  so when it receives something it will put it in a string I found many things but I still don't get the python way of coding it

I guess it will be three lines but I don't get the (read, readable , readline ,....) those python methods.

My question can one familiar to python show me how to write those lines?
I have searched a lot but things a little complicated for me
[the link I tried to understand for so long](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html?highlight=thread#threading)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm still unclear about what you want to achieve. The code you've shown appears to send a file using FTP. Are you asking for the matching code for receiving the file sent? Do you specifically need to use FTP?

Comment: NO I just need a simple code for receiving any string form the server.Always ready so when the server sends it reads this string